# Diagram interval goes slower and slower (Canvas.JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

The problem I am encountering is that when I click to view the diagram via JQuery event click, the diagram works fast and smoothly, but if I double click or perhaps click 10 times, for each click the diagrams runs slower and slower. That is to say the click is dependend on the diagram performance. I believe the `$.getscript()` is causing this low performance, or poor JQuery code..

JQuery event below is responsible for displaying the diagram. Keep in mind that the user has the oppertunity to navigate between the diagrams, they can only view one diagram once.

```
  $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
  var row = $(this).attr('data-row'); 
  $('.active').removeClass('active'); // Displaye:none
  $('#table' + row).addClass('active'); // Display:block

             if(row == 1){
                $.getScript("diagram1.js"); // Display diagram1 
             } else {

             }
        });
```

This is **diagram1.js.**

```
(function (){ 
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var dps = []; // data

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("diagram1 ",
        { 
          title:{
            text: "Exhaust Temperature"  
          data: [
          {        
            type: "spline",
            name: "Temp Cylinder 1",
            showInLegend: "true",
            legendText: "Temp Cylinder 1",
            dataPoints: dps1
          }
        });

        var xVal = 0; 
        var updateInterval = 50; 
        var dataLength = 50; 

    var updateChart = function (count) {
            count = count || 1;
            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {    
                dps.push({
                    x: xVal,
                    y: EXTS[1]       
                });
                xVal++;
            }; 
            if (dps.length > dataLength )
            {
                dps.shift();             
            }
            chart.render();    
        };
        // generates first set of dataPoints
        updateChart(dataLength); 
        // update chart after specified time. 
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 
 });  
}());
```

Comment: $.getScript fetches and executes the JS in question by adding a script element to the DOM. It's not just an expensive way to do this, it's also kind of incoherent. If all you want to do is execute the content of diagram1.js on click, load diagram1.js once, and wrap it in a function that you can call whenever you need it. (In other words, the anon function in diagram1.js can just be a named function without the "$(document).ready" and the iife wrapper. It would be in the global scope, which is not ideal, but is still much better than what's going on currently.)

Comment: Also, I didn't catch this till now: if you execute that repeatedly as-is, you're creating a new setInterval each time. Each one will run every 50 *milliseconds* from whenever they were initialized. The cumulative effect would quickly become extreme. Redrawing is expensive. Is that what you really want to have happening?

Comment: So every time that you click on table row, you are going to fetch another copy of this script, which itself then triggers an anonymous function that introduces another instance of an interval based-execution that runs every 50 milliseconds?  At each interval for each instance you loop will tak longer for every execution since the `count` value increments each time (to max of 50)?  You are introducing a ton of processor-intensive work.  Why do you need updates every 50 ms? That seems to frequent to be practical.

Comment: @Semicolon, I strongly believe that is the problem, because it feels like it gets 50 ms slower and slower. What I did was set updateinterval too 0, but the problem is the same. I believe it copies the diagram over and over again after each call.. Hmm, how could I solve this?

Comment: @MikeBrant, you are correct. The reason I need 50 ms update is because the diagram is dynamic, and it must update in order to fetch data.

Comment: @DierHasan You need to re-think your approach here.  First, reconsider the need to refresh every 50 ms.  That seems extreme.  Second, I don't know what `EXTS` is but it seems like you are are doing in your array of up to 50 items is change the x value.  What benefit is this? You want to draw a straight line?  If so, just draw a line.

Comment: @MikeBrant, Sorry, I did not metion: `EXTS` is data that is being fetched a sensor, and it works. The slow performance after each click is the big issue here.

Comment: Just to confirm: Do you actually want *one* diagram or more than one? Each time you click, you don't just create the diagram fresh; you add *yet another* setInterval. The original setInterval never stops.

Comment: @Semicolon: I have 5 diagrams in total, so the user is going to decide which diagram to view. So if the user clicks on row number 3, then diagram3 will be displayed. Do you understand?

Comment: Okay -- and each of these triggers the load of another file similar to diagram1.js? There are really a lot of problems to unpack here, but I think we've established the immediate issue. You need to only create each diagram (and its interval) once, the first time the row is clicked -- not on every click. Alternatively you could properly destroy and recreate them, including clearInterval, instead of doing display:none.

Comment: @Semicolon, so what exactly should I use clearinterval for, can you give an example?

Comment: @DlerHasan, setInterval has a return value. The value is a unique identifier for the "interval" you just "set". `var x = setInterval(whatever)`; Then when you need the interval to end, you can use `clearInterval(x);`.